# How to build OpenWebRTC on Linux?

Tags: webrtc

I am not sure if i find the information in the net to build openwebrtc in the linux box.

Could someone point out where the instruction are available?

Comment: Their provided instructions on the github repo did not help? https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc/wiki/Building-OpenWebRTC